# vector of characters into expression

Tags: r

I have extracted the variable names of a data frame into a vector of characters of dimension=3000. To use it in supervised learning models I wanted to create an expression similar to

```
var1 + var2 + var3 + ... + var3000
```

that I can use in the model formula of a classification tree. Is there a simple way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: what formula are you looking for?

Comment: If you *really* want a generic expression rather than a formula (i.e. no `~`), please edit your question accordingly (I'd be surprised). What functions/packages are you planning to use for your supervised learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is enough information in your question for me to give you a specific answer, but here's a start...

You can extract the variable names from a data.frame called `df` with:

```
names_vec <- names(df)
```

You can get the desired pattern of variable names with plus signs between them with:

```
string_1 <- paste(names_vec, collapse = " + ")
```

So far, you probably just have the "right side" of a formula that you would like to feed into a modeling function.  Use `paste` again to "complete" the formula by adding a left side (assuming your dependent variable is called `y`):

```
string_2 <- paste("y ~", string_1)
```

Now while this string vector looks like an R formula, it is actually just a string of characters stored in a length-1 vector. R usually "knows" that it should convert this string into a formula, but if you need to do so manually, just wrap wrap the string vector in `formula` as in:

```
lm(formula(string_2), data=df)
```

It is worth mentioning that if you have 3001 variables in your data.frame (one "y" variable and 3000 "x" variables, for example), then you can simply use a period (".") to mean "all other variables" as in:

```
lm(y ~ ., data=df)
```

This will achieve the same result as my 4-step method above.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started...

Comment: upvoted for `y ~ .` also see `?reformulate`, i.e. `reformulate(names_vec,response="y")`

Comment: It's amazing how many R books I've read and still never come across `reformulate`.  There always seems to be a shorter way hiding somewhere! Thanks @BenBolker

Answer (score 1):

@DanY's answer of `y ~ .` is good in many contexts, but *might* not work with all modeling frameworks. `paste()` as described in their answer also works, but `?reformulate` is a simple wrapper for pasting and converting to a formula object, i.e.

```
reformulate(names_vec, response="y")
```

Omit the `response` argument if you want a one-sided formula.